# Need help in Configuring access to Azure users to existing SSO

Tags: azure, spring-security, saml-2.0, openam

Currently we are a Service Provider (SP) which is currently using SSO Authentication using OpenAM and we are using Spring security to achieve this. 
We have a login interface where user enter user name and password and authentication happens.

Now we have a requirement to allow users from an external identity provider (Azure) to access the SP in addition to the existing Open AM SSO. We are trying to use SAML 2.0 to achieve this.

For this we changed the login interface, to accept the user name and based on the user name, we either provide the password option (for local users ) or redirect to the azure portal (for idp users) to authenticate the user.

As part of this requirement, we added a variable userType into httprequest cookie and try to redirect to the respective authentication provider. But we always get redirected to azure even though the user is a local one.

We have gone through many examples from github to implement this but no luck.

Any pointers on this would really be helpful.

Comment: Are you really using OpenAM or are you using ForgeRock Access Management? Furthmore which version of OpenAM or FR AM are you using?

Comment: Hi  Bernhard , We are using ForgeRock Access Management 13.5

Comment: There is no ForgeRock Access Management 13.5. There is only ForgeRock OpenAM 13.5 ... the last open source version. 

There are several ways to achieve this.

1) You could leverage the SAMLv2 authentication module and use a custom auth-module to 'select' the username/password module (e.g. LDAP auth) or the SAMLv2 module (https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13.5/admin-guide/#saml2-module-conf-hints). All in an authentication chain that the OpenAM IdP triggers.
2) Additionally use OpenAM as IdP-Proxy and use an IdP-Finder implementation to either choose OpenAM as IdP or Azure AD IdP